# addition of polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, inverse

If $A+A'=\dfrac{7}{r^2}$, where $A$ and $A'$ are functions of $r$, then is it necessary that $A$ and $A'$ must also be inverse square of $r$? If yes, please tell the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Try $A=r+7/r^2$ and $A'=-r$.

Comment: Perhaps you have a typo in $A'$?  You're spot on if you have $A'=-r$.  I don't know where the "m" comes from?  I will now edit out the "m";  If you later want to roll back the edit, you're free to do so.

Comment: A great answer to a not-so-great question still deserves an upvote